# How to redirect back and display information in a modal in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have list of notifications in a table and with a button beside it to view the recipients in a modal. Here's what I have done:

**notification.blade.php**

```
<div class="recipient_modal">
    <div class="apply_box">
        <div class="rec_close">
            <img src="../../assets/images/close.png" alt="close">
        </div>
        {{-- loop for recipients --}}
    </div>
</div>


<div class="recipients">
     <a class="btn pink rec_btn" href="{{ url('/recipients', 1) }}">Recipients</a>
</div>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/recipients/{news}', 'Admin\NotificationController@recipients');
```

**NotificationController.php**

```
public function recipients()
{
    $messageOne = ['6','7','8'];

    $news = News::with('contest');
    $received = $news->whereIn('message_one', $messageOne)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);

    return Redirect::back()->with(['received'=>$received ]);
}
```

But the problem for this one, it returns Page not Found error. I'm trying to display the recipients information in a modal and I don't have idea for this one. Should I use ajax and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/recipients/{news}', 'Admin\NotificationController@recipients');
```

Because in the above line you had passed a parameter and in your controller file the method name does not have any parameter, your method should be like

```
public function recipients($news)
{
  $messageOne = ['6','7','8'];

  $news = News::with('contest');
  $received = $news->whereIn('message_one', $messageOne)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);

  return Redirect::back()->with(['received'=>$received ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one, but it is still not helping

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using ajax since you are working on a modal. redirect back would definitely refresh the page. With ajax you can get the response in JS and handle it properly. Thanks and goodluck